# ODF to PDF using OO

Tags: java, pdf, odt

Im using OO UNO to create a ODT file...

no matter if in the creation i try to salve in pdf or try to convert latter, i got the same errors:

```
   Connected to a running office ...
com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException: 
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.remoteUnoRequestRaisedException(Job.java:173)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.execute(Job.java:139)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:334)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:303)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JavaThreadPool.enter(JavaThreadPool.java:87)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.sendRequest(java_remote_bridge.java:636)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.request(ProxyFactory.java:146)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:128)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.storeToURL(Unknown Source)
    at cards_certidao.cardmenuitem43.imprimirNegativa(cardmenuitem43.java:465)
    at cards_certidao.cardmenuitem43$2.actionPerformed(cardmenuitem43.java:169)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

the code for conversion:

```
String loadUrl="file:///" + file.getPath(); 
    String storeUrl="file:///" + "F:\\GeradorCertidoesNegativas\\feitas\\" + "["+ nomeDataArquivo + "]" + cboxTipos.getSelectedItem().toString() +"_" + protocolo +"_"
            + nomedopc + "_" + nomeDataArquivo2 + ".pdf"; 

    try { 




        XComponentContext xContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(oooExeFolder); 
        XMultiComponentFactory xMultiComponentFactory = xContext.getServiceManager(); 
        XComponentLoader xcomponentloader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentLoader.class,xMultiComponentFactory.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext)); 

        Object objectDocumentToStore = xcomponentloader.loadComponentFromURL(loadUrl, "_blank", 0, new PropertyValue[0]); 




        PropertyValue pdfFilterData[] = new PropertyValue[2];
        pdfFilterData[0] = new PropertyValue();
        pdfFilterData[0].Name = "SelectPdfVersion";
        pdfFilterData[0].Value = new Integer(1);
        pdfFilterData[1] = new PropertyValue();
        pdfFilterData[1].Name = "UseTaggedPDF";
        pdfFilterData[1].Value = new Boolean("true"); // or false

        PropertyValue[] conversionProperties = new PropertyValue[2];
        conversionProperties[0] = new PropertyValue();
        conversionProperties[0].Name = "FilterName";
        conversionProperties[0].Value = "writer_pdf_Export";
        conversionProperties[1] = new PropertyValue();
        conversionProperties[1].Name = "FilterData";
        conversionProperties[1].Value = pdfFilterData;


        XStorable xstorable = (XStorable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class,objectDocumentToStore); 
        xstorable.storeToURL(storeUrl,conversionProperties); 
    } 
    catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
```

is there something easier to run and generate the PDF from the ODT? JODConverter do not worked for me, ODFDom too...

the only one was something using Python in the OpenOffice folder, but i dont know how to make the java run the command in the folder "C:/OOffice/Program/python Converter.py a.odt b.pdf", it keep running something in background and never ends if i use this command

Comment: OdfDom works well.